# Matlab: Solving a equation: Warning: Explicit solution could not be found

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have a equation like this:
2^n * exp((-p*k*n*(k*n-(k+1)*2^t)))/((k+1)^2*2^(2*t+1))- 1=0.
I tried using the follwing code, but it gives me a warning that "Explicit solution could not be found".

```
syms n k t p positive;
S=solve(2^n * exp((-p*k*n*(k*n-(k+1)*2^t)))/((k+1)^2*2^(2*t+1))- 1,n,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true);
S
```

Is there a way to solve the equation in terms on n?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine in R2013b. Older versions aren't always as adept. Which version do you have? Try not making the variables positive and/or disabling the `'IgnoreAnalyticConstraits'` option.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was using R2011b. I will try with R2013b.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO

MATLAB tries to find an "Explicit" solution, one in which variable *n* is expressed in terms of the other variables. In your case, the solution is ["Implicit"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129122643/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71677.html), meaning that variable *n* cannot be isolated and thus appears on both sides of the equation.

I used a different tool and here is what I got.

[e^((-k^2-k)*n*p*2^t+k^2*n^2*p)=2^(-2*t+**n**-1)/(k^2+2*k+1)]

As you can see, *n* appears on both sides.

You might want to take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557706/how-can-i-implicitly-solve-a-single-equation-in-matlab)